# Create a column and fill it with a certain value if another condition in a different table is met?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've to write a query that retrieves the company name, first line of the street address, city, and a column named Address_Type with the value 'Billing' for customers where the address type in the SalesLT.CustomerAddress table is 'Main Office'.

I've a table called Sa.customer which has the Customer Info like First name , last name , address etc. and another table called SalesLT.CustomerAddress which has Customer ID, Address ID , Address_Type etc. In my query I've to make a new column named "Address Type" with value "Billing" if  the condition address type in SalesLT.CustomerAddress table = 'Main Office' is met.

I've joined multiple tables wherever required and have applied the filter using WHERE command. It has to be a compounded query i.e I have to fill the blank with a command and I cannot add or modify the code between the two lines.

```
SELECT CompanyName, AddressLine1, City, ___ AS Address_Type
FROM SalesLT.Customer AS c
JOIN SalesLT.CustomerAddress AS ca  
  ON c.Customer_ID = ca.Customer_ID  ###-- join based on Customer_ID   
FROM SalesLT.Address AS a       ### -- join another table  
  ON a.Address_ID = ca.Address_ID   ###-- join based on AddressID
WHERE AddressType = 'Main Office'; ###-- filter for where the correct AddressType
```

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images.

Comment: Syntax error. Only one FROM per SELECT.

Comment: To make jarlh's comment more clear - your query should be in the form of <select ... from c inner join ca on .... inner join a on .... where ... order by ...;> And stop the laziness - alias names should not be cryptic one or two letter values.

Comment: I would urge to look at your design a bit. Adding an AddressType column to the table would help for more than just this query. Storing strings over and over like this is painful. If you ever need to change from 'Main Office' you have to update all the address rows. If this was a lookup table it would be much simpler. But really you need to look here. [mcve]

Comment: You can just use `'Billing' as address_type` because the `where` clause is only allowing those addresses.

Answer (score 1):

You can utilize the SQL Server `CASE` statement to construct a value for your `[Address Type]` column by testing the value of the SalesLT.CustomerAddress field for that result tuple:

```
SELECT ...,
  CASE 
    WHEN SalesLT.CustomerAddress LIKE 'Main Office' THEN 'BILLING'
    ELSE ''
  END AS [Address Type],
  ...
FROM ...
WHERE ...
```

However, you will probably find that there are more ways to spell Main Office than you would think if you are dealing with user entered data! I would recommend `TRIM()` on the CustomerAddress field in the CASE statement as well.